# Always Enter Data at The 2nd Row in Excel

Tags: google-sheets

Wants to achieve the same feature with Google Sheets as explained here with MS Excel (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GLjQNeiEeU)

- Only use column A
- 1st Row = Header (Cell A:1)
- 2nd Row (Cell A:2) should always be the cell that one enters data into.
  When you type data and press Enter, the data should move down to Cell A:3 and Cell A:2 should be
  empty again in order to accept the next data input, etc.

Can anyone please assist with a basic script?

Many Thanks
UJ Library

Comment: See the Documentation for `onEdit(event)` here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **Apps Script** that will handle an event such as *editing sheets* and use the **Event Object** to determine which cell is being edited.

Events can be catch using **Triggers**. **Triggers** let Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain event, like editing a sheet, occurs.

**Event Object** contains information about the context that caused the trigger to fire.

### Example:

**Code:**

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  if(range.getA1Notation() == "A2"){
    //Move A2 value below
    range.insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
    //set A2 as active cell
    range.activate();
  }
}
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After pressing Enter:**

[image]

### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [range.activate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate())
- [range.insertCells(shiftDimension)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertcellsshiftdimension)

Comment: Great! Working 100% Thank you so much! Best Regards, Pieter (UJ LIbrary)